# Make two actions on one form

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have payment system on my website.

Right now users make payments in two steps: first step - order is created and placed in my database, second step - i generate form for billing system with "Pay" button and some hidden fields. After user clicks "Pay" - billing system page is loaded and users enters his credit card info.

I want to make it simpler for user - so there will be only one step with "Pay" button. How it can be done?

Comment: For this purpose you can do as follows: For Ex:- you  have to use 1 common page say checking_form.php  and in form action give this page link after that in that page check for action and call your desired page accordingly.

Comment: sorry, i didn't catch - can you explain it bit different?

Comment: To be more specific use one common action i.e. call one common page in action and in that page you can check for actions and according to that specific action you can call your desired page. I hope now you understand.

Answer (score 0):

You can process the both page by adding a Javascipt method to the click method of the submit button (for exemple to display the bill) ...